# Parse linux command line with pipes/redirection using python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

Is there any existing utility that can parse a linux command line with recognition of basic piping and redirection: `'|'`, `'<'`, and, `'>'`? Preferably this can be used for as parameters for a subprocess call instead of using `os.system.`

`shlex.split()` does basic parsing, but its output cannot always be used by `subprocess.Popen` like in this example:

`sed -f script.sed < infile > outfile`

Comment: So you want to rewrite the shell in Python?  Why not simply call the shell instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Such a module would provide nothing that Popen with the shell=True option does not already provide.

See  http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

It won't exist.

Comment: This statement is not correct.  Setting `shell=True` does not enable pipes or redirections with |, > or < - I just checked.

Answer (score 0):

[Hotwire](http://code.google.com/p/hotwire-shell/) seems like it can do this, [this](http://code.google.com/p/hotwire-shell/wiki/HotwireArchitecture) web page has some information on how this works.

[IPython IPipe](http://projects.scipy.org/ipython/ipython/wiki/UsingIPipe) also has a different way to do some of the same things as Hotwire.